# Python a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, wsgiref

I am new to Python. I am running following simple web server:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from io import BytesIO

def message_wall_app(environ, start_response):
    output = BytesIO()
    status = '200 OK' # HTTP Status
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')]
    start_response(status, headers)
    print(b"<h1>Message Wall</h1>",file=output)
##    if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST': 
##        size = int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])
##        post_str = environ['wsgi.input'].read(size)
##        print(post_str,"<p>", file=output)
##    print('<form method="POST">User: <input type="text" '
##          'name="user">Message: <input type="text" '
##          'name="message"><input type="submit" value="Send"></form>', 
##           file=output)         
    # The returned object is going to be printed
    return [output.getvalue()]     

httpd = make_server('', 8000, message_wall_app)
print("Serving on port 8000...")

# Serve until process is killed
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Unfortunately i get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:/xxx/Python/message_wall02.py", line 9, in message_wall_app
    print("<h1>Message Wall</h1>".encode('ascii'),file=output)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'....
```

Please suggest what i am doing wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `print()` to write to binary files. `print()` *converts arguments to `str()`* before writing to a text file object.

From the [`print()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> Print objects to the **text stream** *file*, separated by *sep* and followed by *end*. [...]
>
> **All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does** and written to the stream, separated by *sep* and followed by *end*.

*Bold emphasis mine*. Note that the file object *must* be a text stream, not a binary stream.

Either write to a [`TextIOWrapper()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) wrapping your `BytesIO()` object, call `.write()` on the `BytesIO()` object to write `bytes` objects directly, or write to a [`StringIO()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) and encode the resulting string value at the end.